# Having sbt to re-run on file changes - The `~ compile` equivalent for `run`

Tags: scala, sbt

I know it's possible to re-compile or re-run tests on file changes. I want know to if it's possible to perform something similar for the `run` command. `~ run` does not work. (That makes sense since the run never finishes).

Is there a way to create a task that watches for file changes, quit the running server and relaunch it ?

If not what other tool, would you suggest to get the same behaviour ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to bring in an external project like sbt-revolver

https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver